# Read key/value from object with one key in AngularJS expression

Tags: angularjs

Is there a convenient way to read key/value from an object with only one key in AngularJS expression? Below is an example.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <span>{{me.key}}</span> //I want: <span>name</span>
    <span>{{me.value}}</span> //I want: <span>Ealon</span>
</div>

angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.me = {
            "name": "Ealon" //This object contains only one key
        };
    })
```

Using `ng-repeat` to display the key/value pair is a solution. But unfortunately, I cannot use `ng-repeat` here for some reason.

Another solution, which I think is not convenient, is:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <span>{{meCopy.key}}</span>
    <span>{{meCopy.value}}</span>
</div>

angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.me = {
            "name": "Ealon"
        };

        var meKey = Object.getOwnPropertyNames($scope.me)[0];
        var meValue = $scope.me[meKey];

        $scope.meCopy = {
            "key": meKey,
            "value": meValue
        };
    })
```

Is there any simpler way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you can't use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties), but an alternative option would be using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get at the first property of your object, e.g.:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span>{{getFirstPropertyKey(me)}}</span>
  <span>{{getFirstPropertyValue(me)}}</span>
</div>

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.me = {
          "name": "Ealon" //This object only contains one key
      };

      $scope.getFirstPropertyKey = function(obj){
        return Object.keys(obj)[0];
      }

      $scope.getFirstPropertyValue = function(obj){
        return obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

> But unfortunately, I cannot use `ng-repeat` here for some reason.

Probably you tried to put the `ng-repeat` directive on the same element as the `ng-controller` directive. Both those directives create scopes and will fight each other.

The `ng-repeat` directive needs to be on a different element than the `ng-controller` directive.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in me">
        <span>{{key}}</span>
        <span>{{value}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

By placing the two directives on different elements, scopes created by the `ng-repeat` will properly inherit from the scope created by the `ng-controller` directive.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57e99s5q/)